# jQuery File Upload Plugin: How to upload to subfolders?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the jQuery File Upload plugin working on a PHP site.

I was wondering if it's possible to have the files uploaded into a dynamically-named subfolder rather than all going into the same uploads folder?

Reason being is I need a separate folder for files uploaded in each 'project' being created by the user on the site. E.g. when a user creates a project, everything they upload for that project with go into /uploads/{$project_uid}/{$file_name}

I hope I've explained myself properly and would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out here.

Thanks!

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Uploadify? If you have control over setting which path to upload to in the JavaScript, you should be able to change that path dynamically depending on other variables i.e. project id/file name.

Comment: You cannot upload directly to any folder you like with php, I suppose they all go into a general temp folder first, then you use move_upload_file whereever you want.

Comment: The plugin is called jQuery File Upload, can be found here: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Uploadify seems to suit my purposes better and allows me to achieve what I am trying to do here, so have switched to using that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firt, the obvious should be stated: you **can't** *actually* set the upload destination with JavaScript/jQuery/jWhateverPlugin (i.e. from the client-side), for obvious security reasons.

**But you can** pass information along to the server-side engine (in your case, PHP), which may use it to manage the actual storage of the upload.

Various toolkits exist to help you with, like blueimp's [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) you initially started with, or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), that [Benno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575047/benno) first promoted and seemed to meet your requirements.

So what you have to do is **customize both client-size and server-side scripts** to implement passing along the directory variable(s) and using them to define storage location.

Heavily based on the [Uploadify documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/customizing-the-server-side-upload-script/), and using your `project_uid` variable, this whould look like this:

On the client-side (JavaScript + jQuery + Uploadify):

```js
var project_uid;
// populate project_uid according to your needs and implementation
// befor using uploadify

$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'method'   : 'post',

    // pass your variable to the server
    'formData' : { 'project_uid' : project_uid },

    // optional "on success" callback
    'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) { 
        alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
    }
});
```

And on the server-side (PHP + Uploadify):

```php
// Set $someVar to 'someValue'
$untrustedProjectUid = $_POST['project_uid'];

// Remember to check heavily the untrusted received variable.
// Let's pretend you checked it, it passe your tests, so you
// initialized a trusted var with it
$trustedProjectUid = ensureSecure( $untrustedProjectUid );

$targetFolder = '/uploads/' . $trustedProjectUid . '/' ; // Relative to the root


if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // Put you allowed file extensions here
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo $targetFolder . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
```